# Making a video faster

Tags: video-editor

I’m using Handbrake & have filmed throwing a pot.  I want to make the time it takes shorter.  Can I do this on Handbrake?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you mean. If you want to play back the footage at a higher framerate, then upping the framerate in the export settings should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, Florian.  I want the video to take up less time for the viewer, so I guess each frame must show up in a shorter aunt of time.   I do't know where the 'export settings' are.  I'm a complete novice!

Comment: In that case, I would not recommend using handbrake. There's a free trial version of Premiere, which is widely known and used, and frankly - your task is easier to comprehend compared to handbrake. If you got your video in the timeline, simply right-click and select "speed and duration". When you changed your speed, you can export with ctrl+m and choose h264 mp4 with a bitrate of 4-5 for an average sized, average quality video.

Comment: Thank you so much, Florian.  I'll have a go.

Answer (score 0):

Several approaches were discussed in the comments, but in case somebody is searching for an answer, i will explain more in depth here.

The simplest solutions are to drop some frames or to change the frame rate. Visualy it can be looked at in the following way:

[image: fps change and frame drop]

In here i assume the simple video with 4 frames per second (unrealistic, but it is only for us to get an idea of what is happening) and with only 6 frames. From this we can gather that this video will take 1,5 seconds to be shown to a viewer.

The first thing we can do is to change the frame rate (frames per second, fps). Here i am doubling it. Now there are still the same data in the file, all 6 frames are available, but they will be displayed at the rate 8 per second, and thus the viewer will only see 6/8 of a second worth of video. You should note here that the computer will have to make the same work, but do it faster. Sometimes it means that if the frames are to be displayed faster than they can be read from disk and decoded, the video will start freezing up, random parts will be dropped, other weird things will start happening.

The second thing that we can do is to keep the frame rate the same (4 frames per second), but drop every 3<sup>rd</sup> frame. The effect here will be that the total video will be 1 second long, and the computer will not have to do any more work than usual. However, the data is actually gone from the video now, if we step through the video frame by frame, some frames are completely gone. If you are throwing a pot, i doubt that you will be able to have it fly by in a single frame, but if you are working one a film with a gun shot or something similar, you could potentially lose the frame where something appears on the screen.

And finally, of course, you can do both. This is useful if you are trying to speed things up a lot, but you don't want something like 500fps video, which a computer will simply not be able to handle if the resolution is anything we would consider reasonable.